# Run jQuery script before php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php page which loads a bit slow (SOAP client connection).
In the php page I have a jquery page loader, but the loader is running only after the SOAP client retrives the data (after 30-40 sec).

Is there a way to load the loader script before php script so the end user can view page is loading until the SOAP client retrives all the data ?

php page is strating with below lines

```
<?php 
    session_start();
?>
<?php include 'includes/includes_hotel-rezultate.php';?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

Loader script is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pace.min.js" data-pace-options='{ "ajax": false }'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/page-loading.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can't run javascript before php. PHP is server side, and runs before your browser even knows that the javascript exists. Instead, do an XHR to a php script.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. Server side code (ie. PHP) will *always* be run *before* any JavaScript gets run on the client.

If you want to keep the UI responsive whilst a long running request is made use AJAX.